# If you are sitting completely still inside of a moving car are you at rest?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, reference-frames, inertial-frames, relative-motion

My teacher and I had an argument in class where I stated that motion is undefined without a reference point and that you could just as easily claim that the road is moving backwards at the opposite vector of the car moving forwards.

Comment: You should ask your teacher whether the bystander the car passes is "at rest" or on a rock hurtling through space.

Comment: When your car is moving at constant velocity relative to the road, you are right. But, as @EmilioPisanty has pointed out in his answer below, this holds only for a non-accelerating car!

Comment: If your seat belt is loose, you are at rest w.r.t to the car. When the car hits a wall and you fly into the air bag--not so much.

Comment: Be careful about arguing with your teacher in class.  Teachers have a certain amount of material to present, and long arguments take up valuable time that would have been spent on the lesson plan.

Answer (score 4):

"At rest", when its use is attempted as an absolute term, is meaningless. The term "at rest" must *always* be used relative to a specific frame of reference, and different frames of reference can and will disagree as to what objects are at rest. The choice of reference frame is often implicit in the context (such as the implicit choice of a reference frame co-moving with the (local) surface of the Earth when solving everyday mechanics problems) but that choice can always be subverted by specifying a different frame as the chosen reference.

So: yes, if you're sitting completely still inside a non-accelerating car, then you can legitimately be said to be at rest in the reference frame that co-moves with the car.

Comment: So you mean you cannot be at rest in respect to an accelerating car? How about one of the car seats? Is is at rest or in motion relative to the accelerating car?

Answer (score 0):

You are right.  Motion of an object can only be defined with respect to other objects.  There is no fundamental coordinate system in the universe with respect to which motion can be defined.  The sun is moving with respect to the galactic center, the earth is rotating around the sun, the earth is spinning on its axis -- and the galaxy is moving relative to all the other galaxies.  *Nothing* is "at rest" in any absolute sense; things can at most be at rest relative to each other.

Answer (score 0):

You are at rest in reference to the car — since both of your have the same speed —; but you are moving in reference to the floor, people on the streets, buildings — since you and all of this elements have different speeds.

Your state of motion does depend on what reference frame you use. As a convention, in day-to-day situations, we use the floor as the absolute frame, so we say we are:

1 - moving when: in a moving car, when walking

2 - and we are still when: not distancing ourselves from the original place we were x seconds ago in respect to the ground, where x approaches zero.

Your disagreement with your teacher probably stems from the fact that either your class hasn’t learned relative motion yet and he is trying not to mess with your colleagues heads’, or he isn’t undergraduated in any Hard Science degree and is just there to teach some formulas. The first option is by far the likeliest.

Answer (score 0):

In special relativity, no inertial reference frame is privileged, thus you can consider yourself to be at rest and the earth to be moving. However, while SR does not privilege a particular reference frame, humans do, and "at rest" is generally understood to mean with respect to the earth. In GR, there's the added complication of frame dragging by which one could claim that the earth reference frame is more valid than that of an arbitrary car.